# define aggfunc with two columns as arguments in pandas pivot table

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I want only one value column as a result in below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team':['a','a'],'balance':[100,3],'dpd':[0,60]})
df.pivot_table(index='team',values=['balance','dpd'], 
               aggfunc=lambda x: np.sum(np.where(x.dpd>=30,x.balance,0))/np.sum(x.balance))
```

this return:

```
      balance      dpd
team 
a    0.029126 0.029126
```

But, what I want is a column with new name :

```
        dqratio
team
a       0.029126
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `groupby` and `apply`

```
df.groupby('team').apply(lambda x: np.sum(np.where(x['dpd']>=30,x['balance'],0))/np.sum(x['balance'])).to_frame('dqratio')
       dqratio
team          
a     0.029126
```

Comment: that's what I'm looking for, I think

Comment: how to accept it? I'm some beginner to stack overflow

Comment: @hyunwoojeong in the left of my answer , there is check mark  :-)

Comment: mission completed : )