# Pandas Pivot_Table defined function aggfunc

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to apply a custom aggregation function to a pivot table, but keep receiving KeyError: 'PayoffUPB'. Is this a syntax problem with aggfunc, or do I need to use a lambda function here? Thank you for the help.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([201801,201801,201801,201802,201802,201802,201803,201803,201803], columns=['Month'])
df['Program'] = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']
df['UPB'] = [1000000,1200000,1500000,1300000,1400000,1400000,1000000,1600000,1250000]
df['PayoffUPB'] = [50000,60000,30000,35000,40000,50000,65000,45000,25000]

print(df)

def CPR(x):
    result = 100*(1-(1-x['PayoffUPB'].sum()/x['UPB'].sum())**12)
    return result

df.pivot_table(index='Month',columns='Program',aggfunc=CPR)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [define aggfunc with two columns as arguments in pandas pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244142/define-aggfunc-with-two-columns-as-arguments-in-pandas-pivot-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can using `groupby` with `unstack`

```
df.groupby(['Month','Program']).apply(CPR).unstack()
Out[310]: 
Program          a          b          c
Month                                   
201801   45.963991  45.963991  21.528328
201802   27.928082  29.379551  35.364845
201803   55.358443  28.989114  21.528328
```

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I needed.